# .NET rounding error in ToString("f2")

Tags: c#, c++, floating-point, ieee-754, rounding-error

Hello I have this code in C#:

```
float n = 2.99499989f;
MessageBox.Show("n = " + n.ToString("f2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

And this code in C++:

```
float n = 2.99499989f;
printf("n = %.2f", n);
```

**First** one outputs **3.00**.
**Second** one outputs **2.99**.

I have no clue why this is happening.

**Update:**

I also tried Objective-C **NSLog** and the output is **2.99**.

I needed to fix it fast so I used following method:

```
float n = 2.99499989f;
float round = (float)Math.Round(n, 2);
MessageBox.Show("round = " + round.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

This code shows **2.99**, but computes round in double precision. I can't find Math.RoundF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does printf and co differentiate between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-between-float-and-double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I realize this is an old question, but I'm answering this as I am understanding some things myself...)

My suggestion is that "printf" is converting the float to a double before applying the formatting.
I tried converting the float to a double, and then looking at the double's ToString("f2") result, which it did round in the opposite direction as the float's value was rounded.

Others re-enforce this idea about printf:

> C automatically converts the float values to double (it is a standard conversion made when you call a function that takes variable arguments, such as int printf...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480244/119418

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395747/119418

I believe the reason the float rounds up is because 2.995F doesn't convert perfectly into binary and is = 2.99499989F, and we'd expect 2.995 to round up.

I believe the reason the float copied into a double rounds down is because 2.995 as a double <> 2.99499989 as a double, and 2.995 actual double value is greater than that value (more precision closer to its true decimal value), and so that value we'd expect to round down.

It might seem wrong that 2.99499989F rounds up to 3.00 even though it is seemingly less than 2.995, but keep in mind that the 2.99499989 is a decimal, not a float, and you are "converting" it into a float, basically converting base-10 to base-2, and it is really 1's and 0's, then asking it to be rounded in base-10 terms, which means a conversion has to happen.  Well, there are at least 2 base-10 values that I mentioned that can convert to that number as a float, and the simplest of those is 2.995.

Answer (score 7):

Using `BitConverter.GetBytes` and printing out the actual bytes produced shows that this is **not** a *compiler* difference - in both cases, the actual float value stored is `0x403FAE14`, which [this handy calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?hexadecimal=403FAE14) tells me is the exact value

```
2.99499988555908203125
```

The difference therefore must lie in differing behaviours of `printf` and `ToString`. More than that I cannot immediately say.

Answer (score 0):

First one rounds the number incorrectly.

Second one only selects two digits after comma, I guess.

Maybe some floating-point-precission issues? 2.9949... in fact rounds to more than 2.995?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that due to the fact that a 'float' isn't 'that' precise ?

Check this out, when you use a decimal:

```
        // float
        Console.WriteLine (2.99499989f.ToString ("f2"));
        // The above line outputs 3.00

        // decimal
        Console.WriteLine (2.99499989M.ToString ("f2"));
        // The above line outputs 2.99
```

Perhaps float can't represent 2.99499989 or whatever as 2.99.
Look also what happens when you do this:

```
// float
Console.WriteLine (2.98499f.ToString ("f2"));
// The above line outputs 2.99
```

Comment: What *does* happen when you use those? Can't you print the output as well as the code, so we don't have to paste it into a compiler to make sense of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The float precision is `2^{-23}` or about `0,0000001192` (relative error).
Look, 2.995-2.99499989 = 0,00000011. Relative error is `3,6*10^{-8}`.

If some compiler reads all digits of the `2.99499989f` constant then the result is number greater than 2.995. But if another compiler reads only `2.994999` (because the precision is less than 2^{-23} and last digits are unimportant) then the result is number less than 2.995

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How would the first compiler get `2.99499989f > 2.995`?

Comment: No problem. Compiler must choose between 2.9950001239776611328125E0 and 2.99499988555908203125. Only these values is valid by IEEE754.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the explanation is that `float.ToString()` rounds twice as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085052/round-twice-error-in-nets-double-tostring-method)

The following code in C#:

```
float f = #NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10#;
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("f2"));
```

and the following code in C:

```
float f = #NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10#;
printf("%.2f", f + 5e-7);
```

Should yield the same output. In particular the C# code:

```
float f = 2.99499989f;
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("f2"));
```

yields `3.00` and the C code:

```
float f = 2.99499989f;
printf("%.2f", f + 5e-7);
```

also yields `3.00`

Answer (score -2):

The number 2.99499989f can't be presented exactly in IEEE754. Apparently printf and ToString handle this situation differently.

Comment: As AakashM shows, the actual value stored is 2.99499988555908203125, which is more than close enough that ToString *should* give a correct answer.

Comment: Sure, but let's suppose that ToString just adds 0.005 to round to the nearest 2 decimals. In that case you get 2.99999989f which representation is 0x40400000. Which happens to be exactly 3.