# How does printf and co differentiate between float and double

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

Since it isn't strongly typed I thought it just picked the right memory size and interpreted it based on the type of argument. But float and double both use %f and they are different sizes.

P.S.
I can see how promotion via copying the value to a temp and casting(is this right?) might work
but how does it work for scanfs/sscanf?

Comment: [Why does printf() promote a float to a double?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28097564/995714)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It doesn't differentiate. It's not possible to receive a `float` as a vararg: any `float` argument that you provide is first promoted to `double`.

6.5.2.2/6 defines "default argument promotions", and /7 states that default argument promotions are applied to "trailing arguments", that is varargs denoted by `...`.

> how does it work for scanfs/sscanf?

The `%f` format for `scanf` requires a pointer to `float`. `%lf` requires a pointer to `double`, `%Lf` requires a pointer to `long double`.

> copying the value to a temp and casting(is this right?)

If you provide a float argument, then the implementation creates a temporary of type double, initializes it with the float value, and passes this as the vararg. Casting by definition is *explicit* conversion by use of the cast operator -- you can cast if you like in order to make it exactly clear to the reader what's going on, but `float f = 3; printf("%f", f);` is exactly the same as `float f = 3; printf("%f", (double)f);`. The default argument promotion has the same meaning as the cast.

Comment: Thanks, do printfs(standard or extensions) accept that for double as well to keep symmetry?

Comment: Oh, if you mean "can I use %lf and %Lf as formats in `printf` and co" then yes, you can. %lf is exactly the same as %f, both take a `double`. %Lf takes a `long double`.