# C90 doesn't allow %lf use in printf, why?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner programming student, just wanted to learn the reason behind this.

When I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 double pi = 3.1415926535897932;
 printf("%lf",pi);
 return 0;
}
```

Compiler gives this warning. 
ISO C90 does not support the ‘%lf’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat]

I use the gcc compiler in ubuntu terminal with (-o -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors)

What's the reason behind this? I searched web and found this use is allowed in C99. Why C90 didn't allow %lf use in printf? I can use %.16lf or %.16f and both print with the same precision, so what's the matter that makes %lf bad in C90?

Comment: Because it wasn't standardized until later?

Comment: `%lf` has no use for the `printf` family, only for the `scanf` family.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double

Comment: you probably just confused things, `double` is printed with `%f` and not `%lf`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to C90 documentation:

> an optional l (ell) specifying that a following d , i , o , u , x , or
>   X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int
>   argument; an optional l specifying that a following n conversion
>   specifier applies to a pointer to a long int argument; or an optional
>   L specifying that a following e , E , f , g , or G conversion
>   specifier applies to a **long double** argument. **If an h , l , or L
>   appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Answer (score 5):

C is an evolving language. New features and behaviors get added in every new release of the C standard.

C89 says that `l` before `f` leads to undefined behavior. And C90 probably says the same.

C99 on the other hand says that `l` before `f` has no effect.