# Structure within union in C

Tags: c, structure, unions

When a variable is associated with a union, the  compiler allocates the  memory by considering the size of the largest memory. So, size of union is equal to the size of largest member. so it means Altering the value of any of the member will alter other member values.
but when I am executing the following code,

```
output: 4 5 7.000000
union job
{
    int a;
    struct data
    {
        double b;
        int x
    }q;
} w;


w.q.b=7;
w.a=4;
w.q.x=5;

printf("%d %d %f",w.a,w.q.x,w.q.b);
return 0;
}
```

Issue is that, first I assign the value of a and later modified the value of q.x, then the value of a would be overridden by q.x. But in the output it still shows the original value of a as well as of q.x. I am not able to understand why it is happening?

Comment: I believe that the OP's edit shows very clearly what the question is (I am rephrasing): "how come the numbers didn't change when I am supposed to have overwritten the data in the structure". And I have an answer ready... I just can't post it while the question is closed.

Comment: @Floris it's open now. Awaiting your answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks - it's there now.

Comment: You said "size of union is equal to the size of largest member" Is that guaranteed by the specification, or is it only *typically* true?  (Not a rhetorical question; I don't know the answer.) If it matters to you, you might want to post that as a question.

Comment: @EricLippert: per definition, but in this case the size depends on the padding and alignment (if any) of the `struct` members.

Comment: @Jongware I agree - I touched upon that in my answer. In this case, `sizeof(w) == 16` although you might think it would be `12`.

Answer (score 8):

Your understanding is correct - the numbers should change. I took your code, and added a little bit more, to show you exactly what is going on.

The real issue is quite interesting, and has to do with the way floating point numbers are represented in memory.

First, let's create a map of the bytes used in your struct:

```
aaaa
bbbbbbbbxxxx
```

As you can see, the first four bytes of `b` overlap with `a`. This will turn out to be important.

Now we have to take a look at the way `double` is typically stored (I am writing this from the perspective of a Mac, with 64 bit Intel architecture. It so happens that the format in memory is indeed the IEEE754 format):

[image]

The important thing to note here is that Intel machines are "little endian" - that is, the number that will be stored first is the "thing on the right", i.e. the least significant bits of the "fraction".

Now let's look at a program that does the same thing that your code did - but prints out the contents of the structure so we see what is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void dumpBytes(void *p, int n) {
  int ii;
  char hex[9];
  for(ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    sprintf(hex, "%02x", (char)*((char*)p + ii));
    printf("%s ", hex + strlen(hex)-2);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
static union job
{
    int a;
    struct data
    {
        double b;
        int x;
    }q;
} w;


printf("intial value:\n");
dumpBytes(&w, sizeof(w));
w.q.b=7;
printf("setting w.q.b = 7:\n");
dumpBytes(&w, sizeof(w));
w.a=4;
printf("setting w.a = 4:\n");
dumpBytes(&w, sizeof(w));
w.q.x=5;
printf("setting w.q.x = 5:\n");
dumpBytes(&w, sizeof(w));

printf("values are now %d %d %.15lf\n",w.a,w.q.x,w.q.b);
w.q.b=7;
printf("setting w.q.b = 7:\n");
dumpBytes(&w, sizeof(w));
printf("values are now %d %d %.15lf\n",w.a,w.q.x,w.q.b);
return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
intial value:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

All zeros (I declared the variable `static` - that makes sure everything will be initialized). Note that the function prints out 16 bytes, even though you might have thought that a struct whose biggest element is `double + int` should only be 12 bytes long. This is related to byte alignment - when the largest element is 8 bytes long, the structure will be aligned on 8 bit boundaries.

```
setting w.q.b = 7:
00 00 00 00 00 00 1c 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Let's look at the bytes representing the `double` in their correct order:

```
40 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00

Sign bit = 0
exponent = 1 0000 0000 0111b  (binary representation)
mantissa = 0

setting w.a = 4:
04 00 00 00 00 00 1c 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

When we now write `a`, we have modified the first byte. This corresponds to the least significant bits of the mantissa, which is now (in hex):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 04
```

Now the format of the mantissa implies a `1` to the left of this number; so changing the last bits from `0` to `4` in changed the magnitude of the number by just a tiny fraction - you need to look at the 15th decimal to see it.

```
setting w.q.x = 5:
04 00 00 00 00 00 1c 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The value `5` is written in its own little space

```
values are now 4 5 7.000000000000004
```

Note - when I used a large number of digits, you can see that the least significant part of `b` is not exactly `7` - even though a double is perfectly capable of representing an integer accurately.

```
setting w.q.b = 7:
00 00 00 00 00 00 1c 40 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
values are now 0 5 7.000000000000000
```

After writing `7` into the double again, you can see that the first byte is once again `00`, and now the result of the `printf` statement is indeed 7.0 exactly.

So - your understanding was correct. The problem was in your diagnosis - the number was different but you couldn't see it.

Usually a good way to look for these things is to just store the number in a temporary variable, and look at the difference. You would have found it easily enough, then.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey you are right and I remembered incorrectly (I guess I recently got bitten by the `scanf` issue and it made me more careful about "correct" format specifiers. Reference - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6395747/1967396 . I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can see altered values if you run the below code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

union job
{
    struct data
    {
         int x;
         double b;       
    }q;
    int a;
} w;

int main() {

    w.q.b=7;
    w.a=4;
    w.q.x=5;

    printf("%d %d %f",w.a,w.q.x,w.q.b);
    return 0;
 }
```

OUTPUT: 5 5 7.000000

I have slightly modified the structure inside the union, but that explains your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy the instruction `w.a = 4` overrides the data of `w.q.b`. Here is how your memory looks like:

```
After   w.q.b=7;    After   w.a=4;      After   w.q.x=5;

|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|   \       \
|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|   |0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|   |0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|   |   w.a |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |       |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|   /       |   w.q.b
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|           |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|           |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|           |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|           /

-----------------   -----------------   -----------------

|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   \
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |   w.q.x
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|   |0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|   /
```

As you can see the 30th bit of `w.q.b` is changed from `0` to `1` due to the assignment of `4` to the first 4 bytes, but this change is too low as only the mantissa part is affected and the precision of printing `w.q.b` doesn't show this change.

Comment: You have the right idea, but I think you have your endianness messed up. But maybe you are working on a big-endian machine? See my answer and the output it generated. In your bit map the change that writing `a` made is rather close to the exponent bits - thus near the most significant bits of the mantissa. Have to say I like the "bit art" though!

Comment: Clarification on "endianness". Bytes are stored sequentially in memory. For instance, if you have the number `4` as an `int`, the four bytes needed to store it are `00 00 00 04`. In a "little endian" machine, they are actually stored `04 00 00 00` ("littlest byte first"). Same for doubles etc. Your diagram supposes that things are stored in "natural" (big endian) order; that's true on some platforms (68000 series, PPC) but not on [most] Intel (x86) machines. In this case, the difference matters - it changes which bits of the `double` are overwritten by the `int`.

Comment: @Floris Tanks for the clarification!