# How come printf handles a float argument exactly the same way it handles a double argument?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

**Until very recently, I thought that:**

- `printf("%f",x)` would attempt to read a 4-byte floating-point value from the stack.
- `printf("%lf",x)` would attempt to read an 8-byte floating-point value from the stack.

**However, the following piece of code seems to yield the correct output:**

```
float  f = 1234.5;
double d = 12345678.9;
printf("Output = %u %u\n",sizeof(f),sizeof(d)); // Output = 4 8
printf("Output = %.1f %.1f\n",f,d);             // Output = 1234.5 12345678.9
```

I believe that it proves that `printf("%f",x)` reads an 8-byte floating-point value from the stack.

This is because both values are printed correctly, yet 12345678.9 is too large to fit into a 4-byte variable.

Now my question is: when calling `printf` with a 4-byte `float` variable, how does the compiler know that it should cast it to an 8-byte `double` value before pushing it into the stack and calling `printf`?

Is that a part of the standard when calling functions that take floating-point arguments?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double It is a va_args issue.

Comment: Oh... so this is the case **only** when passing a `float` variable to a function that takes a variable number of arguments (via `vararg`) such as `printf`?

Comment: Yes, you can pass char and float, but you have to retrieve them as int and double.

Comment: OK, I have realized it in the past about `char` and `short`, but figured it was a "rounding up to a multiple of 4" that would take place for **every** function call (hence assumed that `char/short/int/float` would all be passed as 4-byte arguments, regardless of the `vararg` issue)... Thanks for the info :)

Comment: Since you know that `printf` arguments must match the format string, use either `…%zu…", sizeof(…)` or `…%u…", (unsigned int)sizeof(…)`. Printing the result of `sizeof` with `%u` can fail because `size_t` does not have to be `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thanks for the info... BTW, it will just print the wrong output (won't cause any memory access violations or anything)

Comment: @barakmanos: well, maybe.  The behavior is undefined, so it actually could do *anything*.  I prefer "use your credit card to order a burrito for a randomly chosen compiler engineer" as the default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how does the compiler know that it should cast it to an 8-byte double value before pushing it into the stack and calling printf?

It doesn't have to know when to do it - it always does; it's part of the [*default argument promotions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls).

> Is that a part of the standard when calling functions that take floating-point arguments?

No, just variadic ones.