# C double value not stored using scanf

Tags: c, double

So what is happening is I ask the user for input, then store that into a variable using scanf.

But when I try to retrieve the value, it just a 0.000000. I'm sure I'm just making a stupid noob mistake, but any help you can provide is appreciated.

```
printf("Enter the radius of your circle/sphere: ");
scanf("%f", &radius);

printf("\n%f", radius);
```

Ex:

Enter the radius of your circle/sphere: 10

0.0000000

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried using `%lf` (if your variable `radius` *is* a `double`, since you didn't show your declaration) ?

Comment: Also should check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: I would have better reputation if I bothered to put these in answers instead of comments :D

Comment: How did you declare radius?

Comment: THANKS! Radius is a double. I didn't know that I was supposed to use lf for doubles. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with scanf and doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890748/problems-with-scanf-and-doubles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by @Chris McGrath, you must use the `%lf` format specifier for doubles. However, this doesn't explain why the `%f` format works just fine for `printf`.

`%lf` stands for long `float`, i.e. `double`. When values of type `float` are passed to variadic functions (those accepting a variable number of arguments, such as `printf` and `scanf`), they are implicitly promoted to `double`:

```
float val;
printf("%f", val);   /* printf receives val cast to double, the same
                        as printf("%f", (double) val) */
printf("%lf", val);  /* printf also receives val cast to double, the
                        same as printf("%lf", (double) val) */
```

Since both `printf("%lf", ...)` and `printf("%f", ...)` end up receiving a `double`, the two are completely equivalent.

On the other hand, all arguments to `scanf` are pointers. `scanf("%f", ...)` expects to receive a `float *`, and `scanf("%lf", ...)` a `double *`:

```
float floatval;
double dblval;
scanf("%f", &floatval); /* stores a float value to address received */
scanf("%lf", &dblval);  /* stores a double value to address received */
```

The two pointers point to different types, so one cannot be promoted to the other. If they received the same treatment by `scanf`, it would end up storing the same value into addresses allocated for types of different size, which cannot work.

This is why `scanf` strictly requires the use of the `%lf` specifier when used with `double` values.

Comment: `long float` is not a synonym for `double`, it's a syntax error. The floating-point types are `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Corrected, thanks. BTW you made the same error in your comment.

Comment: Not anymore I didn't!

Comment: @user4815162342: I have previously asked a similar question and got sort of an opposite answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21443160/1382251... Well, to be more accurate, I asked how come `printf("%f",x)` works for both `float x` and `double x`. Can you please refer to that (if not too hard)? Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos The answer to that question is essentially the same as the first part of my answer, where I explain why `%f` and `%lf` are the same for `printf`. This answer goes one step further to explain how come the two are **not** the same for `scanf`, which doesn't directly receive variadic floating-point values, but pointers to ones. Pointers don't (and can't) fall under the default promotion rules, so `%lf` and `%f` must do different things in order to store values of different types. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/210591/1600898) states the same, but doesn't explain why.

Comment: @user4815162342: Oh!!!!!! `scanf` takes pointers, of course!!! Sorry, I should have realized that (or read your answer a little more carefully)... Thanks, gave you a tenner :)

Comment: Additional note: C89 doesn't have `printf("%lf", ...)`, although many compilers implemented it as an extension. It wasn't formally added until C99. C89 specifies that `%f` is the specifier for both `float` and `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate understanding the logic behind the fix, not just the fix itself. All of you have been very helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As AntonH said, if radius is declared as a double, you must use the `%lf` format specifier:

```
scanf("%lf", &radius);
```