# Avoiding floating point warning

Tags: avr, floating

i am programming ATmega128 using avr studio 4. When I display floating point values, I get warning message which says

Lines causing warning message to appear are as follows :

```
float temperature;
//{other parts}
fprintf(stderr,"Temp: %0.2f ", temperature);
```

warning message is:

```
../main.c:128:2: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 4 has type 'float' [-Wformat]"
```

When displaying it in double, I see other random values..How can I get rid of this warning message ?

Comment: Please post some code or at least the line thats causing the error (../main.c:128:2) and maybe the output value(s) you get and you expect.

Comment: Is this of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double -- I'd suggest explicitly casting to double (wich is the same as float in avr-gcc) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Rev1.0 - I have pasted lines from my code. Output reading from the temperature sensor is as expected when using above shown declaration  but I get warning message expecting double value. I wanted to get rid of this.

Comment: @Hanno Binder - I went through link provided by you. What I understood is that when using printf, float argument is converted to double. Since I did not have to deal with double before I did not care about it. But I have one simple question. In avr-gcc can I use double instead of float if size does not matter. and does avr-gcc treat float and double in same way ?

Comment: Well, `temperature` should be implicitly promoted to `double` in any case. What exactly do you mean with "When displaying it in double, I see other random values". You mean when you explicitly cast to `double` the displaed value is wrong? I don't see why that should happen.

Comment: Regarding float and double in avrgcc: Both are implemented with 4-Byte length and have exactly the same internal format. However, they are still different types.

Comment: Btw, "using avr studio 4". Why do you do that?! :) I read in Rev1.0's answer that it's been fixed in gcc 4.1! - We're at 4.8.x now. Consider upgrading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further digging and the warning is/was actually a bug with AVRGCC. It was [marked as resolved in GCC v4.1.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35649) but judging the comments it wasn't properly fixed. There was [another fix](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/c/c-typeck.c?r1=200683&r2=202006&pathrev=202006) on Aug 26 16:52:19 2013 UTC which probably fixed the issue as desired.

It seems the `float` to `double` promotion wasn't working properly because the GCC code assumed two different sizes for both types.