# Inconsistent Floating Point Output

Tags: c, floating-point

I would like to better understand floating point values and the imprecisions associated.

Following are two snippets with slight modifications

**Snippet 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   float a = 12.59;
   printf("%.100f\n", a);
}
```

Output:

12.5900001525878906250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**Snippet 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("%.100f\n", 12.59);
}
```

Output:

12.589999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Why is there a difference in both the outputs? I'm unable to understand the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you have defined variable as a float and in second case you directly given the number.

System might be consider direct number as a double and not float.

So,I think may be it is because of system definition of float and double.

Answer (score 2):

to get the consistent behaviour you can explicitly use floating point literal:

```
printf("%.100f\n", 12.59f);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Snippet 1, your float gets cast into a double, and this casting causes a change in the value (due to the intricacies of floating point representation).

In Snippet 2, this cast doesn't happen, it's printed directly as a double.

To understand, try running the snippets below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double a = 12.59;
    printf("%.100f\n", a);  
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(void) {
    float a = 12.59;
    printf("%.100f\n", (double)a);  
    return 0;
}
```

Refer to this for more information: [How does printf and co differentiate beetween float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double)