# C print long long to float

Tags: c

I have two long long (int) values, and I want to print their division in float format with 3 digits precision. I have already read
[printf and long double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double) , but all those suggestions lead to `nan` as the result of printf.
E.g.

```
  long long a = 123123123;
  long long b = 123123124;
  printf("%d\n", b/a);
  printf("%.3f", b/a);
```

The first print will output `1` (as expected), but the second `0.000` instead of `1.xxx`

Comment: you have to explicitly cast: `printf("%.3f", (float)b/a);`

Comment: You must cast either one of a or b to floating point first. Try: a/(double)b.

Comment: The first one is wrong, too: `%d` takes an `int`, not a `long long int`. You need `%lld` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the first one, `printf` doesn't check the passed arguments or the number of formatting arguments of the string vs the arguments (most compilers can warn you about problems, but that's not guaranteed)

`b/a` is a `long long` type.

So even if the first `printf` kind of works, it would be better with

```
printf("%lld\n", b/a);
```

second `printf` doesn't work at all because argument is interpreted as a `double`, but not converted (although passing a `float` would also work: [How does printf and co differentiate beetween float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double)) , due to the varadic nature of the `printf` function (you can virtually pass anything as argument, so it's not safe). You have to convert it to `double` explicitly for instance like this:

```
printf("%.3f", (double)b/a);
```

Note that `(double)(b/a)` would also work but you'd lose the decimal part

Comment: printf `%f` takes a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: No, printf `%lf` has undefined behavior in C89 and was made equivalent to `%f` in C99.

Comment: ok, that's for `scanf`. But casting to `float` works, even if it's not optimal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-beetween-float-and-double. However, edited because it's better to cast to `double`

Comment: I used casts for so long.. but still forgot about them :|