# Why does %f print large values when floating point constants are passed instead of variables?

Tags: c

In the given program why did I get different results for each of the `printf`s?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float c = 4.4e10;
    printf("%f\n", c);
    printf("%f\n", 4.4e10);
    return 0;
}
```

And it shows the following output:

```
44000002048.000000
44000000000.000000
```

Comment: The answers so far explain that `4.4e10` is a `double` constant which is converted to `float` in the initialization of `c` but kept as a `double` when passed to `printf`. However, you might also like to know that adding an `f` suffix makes it a `float` constant: Printing `4.4e10f` will show the same value that results from initializing `c` to `4.4e10f`. Distinguishing `float` constants from `double` constants can be important to doing quality work with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Is this conversion method named anything? I want to read about it.

Comment: Do you want to know when the conversion from `double` to `float` occurs in the C language? Or do you want to know what values result from the conversion, that is, what effects the conversion has? Or something else?

Comment: I'm questioning ***neither*** the replies here ***nor*** the standard but, when I was young and learning `C` we used `printf("%f",x)` for a `float` and `printf("%lf",x)` for a `double`. When did things change? And how would one *explicitly* printf a (single) `float` - `printf("%hf",x)`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['float' vs. 'double' precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

Comment: @Adrian `%lf` in printf is the same thing as `%f`. A `float` in a variable argument is converted into a `double` by the compiler, just like a `short` gets converted into an `int`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-between-float-and-double and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097564/why-does-printf-promote-a-float-to-a-double and maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf

Comment: See also the canonical question on these issues, [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)

Answer (score 9):

A `float` is a type that holds a 32-bit floating point number, while the constant `4.4e10` represents a `double`, which holds a 64-bit floating point number (i.e. a *double*-precision floating point number)

When you assign `4.4e10` to `c`, the value `4.4e10` cannot be represented precisely (a rounding error in a parameter called the mantissa), and the closest possible value (44000002048) is stored. When it is passed to `printf`, it is [promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395726/how-does-printf-and-co-differentiate-between-float-and-double) back to `double`, including the rounding error.

In the second case, the value is a `double` the whole time, without narrowing and widening, and it happens to be the case that a `double` can represent the value exactly.

If this is undesirable behavior, you can declare `c` as a `double` for a bit more precision (but beware that you'll still hit precision limits eventually).

Answer (score 3):

You're actually printing the values of two different types here.

In the first case you're assigning a value to a variable of type `float`.  The precision of a `float` is roughly 6 or 7 decimal digits, so unless the value can be represented exactly you'll see the closest value that can be represented by that type.

In the second case you're passing the constant `4.4e10` which has type `double`.  This type has around 16 decimal digits of precision, and the value is within that range, so the exact value is printed.

Comment: Why it specifically prints 2048 at the end ?

Comment: @user10056563 Because that's the closest number to 4.4e10 that can be stored in a 32 bit float.