# c printf %lf %d different result

Tags: c, printf

#### MyCode

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("result1 : %lf %d\n", (1 - (double)((int)1)), (1 - (double)((int)1)));
  return 1;
}
```

#### Result

```
result1 : 0.000000, 1
```

I dont't understand this result.

#### I think when printf("%d"), this result must be zero!

Comment: The `%d` part is *undefined behavior* - your result cannot be a `double` and an `int` at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) reference to find that the `"%d"` format specifier expects an `int` as parameter. Yet, you pass it a `double`. This is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), meaning anything can happen, including the result you get (for more details on what's likely happening, refer to eg. [What happens to a float variable when %d is used in a printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480097/what-happens-to-a-float-variable-when-d-is-used-in-a-printf)).

Instead, try adding a cast to `int` :

```
printf("result1 : %lf %d\n", (1 - (double)((int)1)), (int) (1 - (double)((int)1)));
```

Comment: Good explanation, you could also add why the second result is casted as double and not as Integer in the OP`s question

Comment: @Alan : I'm unsure what you mean. The third parameter *is* a `double` (due to the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)), just like the second parameter (it is the same expression after all).

Comment: My question was, as you cast the second result to (double) (int) what`s the precedence, why does It get casted double and not int

Comment: @Alan : you should really ask your own question for that, but simply put : [type casts are right-to-left associative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Got it thanks Sander!

Answer (score 1):

The type of the arguments passed to `printf` have nothing inherently to do with the format string. It is your responsibility to make sure the types match up. In this case, you are passing two `double` values. However, the format string is attempting to interpret the second one as an integer. This is undefined behavior.

While the behavior is undefined in the general case, it is likely that you are seeing the sign bit of the IEEE 754 double in a little-endian interpretation of an integer.