# float calculation display output is different to the debug result

Tags: c#

Im struggling to understand why a calculation in c# is displaying a different result in a console window compared to the result in debug.

The following code displays 0.1647513 in the console 0.1647513 and in debug 0.164751321

```
        var v = (float) (0.172731235 + -0.200918653*0.04 + 0.03552264*0.04*0.04);
        Console.WriteLine(v);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Can anyone explain this please

Thanks

Comment: Well the code you've given doesn't display *anything* in the console. It's not clear what you mean by "in debug" either.

Comment: This link can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421520/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c-sharp

Comment: Sorry, ive updated the code. What I mean by debug is when I breakpoint the code and evaluate the variable "v"

Comment: The debugger just shows more digits. For `float` those are irrelevant as they are beyond the accurate range of the data type here. Keep in mind that this is binary floating-point, not decimal, so the decimal representation is almost always much longer, but without adding any accuracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is here: [C# float.ToString Rounding Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119509/c-sharp-float-tostring-rounding-values)

Basically, a float by default holds 7 digits (what you're seeing in the output) - but it can also hold 9 (what you're seeing when you break execution and take a look).

Try `Console.WriteLine(v.ToString("G9");` and see if it prints the same

Comment: Thanks for the answer simonalexander2005, although I still don't understand the benefit of why displaying the result is different to the actual value.